# Solidity-extension in VS Code can't resolve the imports from node_modules

Tags: javascript, solidity, smartcontracts, visual-studio-extensions, truffle

Please take a look at my environment details.

**Environment**

- Node installed with `nvm`
- Truffle is installed in different node environments which can be switched by simply changing the node by `nvm use v16.17.0`
- In my vs code I have installed Truffle for VS Code extension, which is also tightly dependent on solidity extension.
- I have installed `Ganache` desktop application.
- I also have `solcjs` installed as `npm` package in one of my node versions.

**Contract**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity >=0.4.25 <0.9.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract CallerContract is Ownable {

}
```

**Project Structure**
The node modules are installed one folder behind the truffle project for contract as shown below.

```
├── caller
│   ├── build
│   ├── contracts
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── test
│   └── truffle-config.js
├── oracle
│   ├── build
│   ├── contracts
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── test
│   └── truffle-config.js
├── node_modules
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
```

**Output**

- truffle compile works fine in terminal by using `truffle compile` in all the node versions.
- In VS code truffle extension's Truffle contract explorer part successfully compiles the contract.

**Failure**

- I am facing one failure and that is when I right-click `Solidity: Compile Contract`. It outputs

```
Retrieving compiler information:
Compiler using default compiler (embedded on extension), solidity version: 0.8.9+commit.e5eed63a.Emscripten.clang
ParserError: Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol" not found: File import callback not supported
 --> path to contracts/contracts/CallerContract.sol:7:1:
  |
  | import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


Compilation failed with 1 errors
```

And I have tried many ways to resolve this as mentioned here, mainly this solution.

```
"solidity.packageDefaultDependenciesContractsDirectory": "",
"solidity.packageDefaultDependenciesDirectory": "node_modules",
```

Answer (score 1):

I am in the same situation. I tried the vscode settings also to no avail.
Googleing in circles seems to be an environment issue.

My workaround is to prepend the imports with the path as such:

`import "../nodemodules/@openzeppelin-etc".....`

And then when I need to actually compile in Hardhat I change them back
Not ideal - hopefully someone has a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. What resolved this for me was going to the Solidity extension settings, then `Package Default Dependencies Directory`, then click on `Edit in settings.json` and adding this line:

```json
    "solidity.packageDefaultDependenciesDirectory": "node_modules",
```

The error went away without restarting VS Code. I hope this helps!

Comment: this worked for me strangely despite node_modules being nested

Answer (score 0):

Say your repo structure looks like this (openzeppelin-solidity is in node_modules):

[image]

If you open vscode at the root level, you should config as follows:

```
"solidity.packageDefaultDependenciesContractsDirectory": "",
"solidity.packageDefaultDependenciesDirectory": "src/node_modules"
```

Because solidity extension for Vscode resolves imports from top level of the opened folder in Vscode.
If you have multiple projects in different folders it may also intefere with the extension's abilities to resolve imports and it would be better to open each of the project separately(one by one).
Most important node_modules folder shall be included on root level of the opened Vscode folder